# xml comment in output of cfscript tag

Tags: xml, json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to output a query object as JSON. I found some code that suggested using the ColdFusion `cfscript` tag along with the `serializeJSON` function:

```
<cfscript>
  theJSON = SerializeJSON(queryObj);
  writeOutput(theJSON);
</cfscript>
```

This works to create JSON from the query object. However at the end of the outputted json is an xml comment is always appended like this:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","VALUE"],"DATA":[["12345","abcd"]]} <!-- 113760 -->
```

The number inside the xml comment always being randomly generated. Because this is xml it is not valid json. I would like to get rid of it but I am not sure how. Any ideas why this xml is showing up or how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Can you post the XML you are trying to convert?

Comment: I doubt it is caused by serializeJSON. Is there any other code on your test page or an application.cfm/cfc involved?

Comment: It looks like your doubts were well founded, I looked again and found that my page also included this statement: <cfcontent type="application/json"> which turned out to be the culprit. But I would like to have the content set to JSON without having a xml comment tacked onto the output. Any suggestions?

Comment: `cfcontent` should not have that effect either. It just sets a request header. Can you post a stand alone example that produces the extra comment you are seeing?

Comment: I agree with @Leigh.  All `<cfcontent>` does in that case is set the response's MIME type.  A solid repro case would help here.

Comment: Did you ever figured out what the problem was?

Comment: I did finally figure the real reason out. See my explanation in the comment on the marked answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have something else outputting that comment. Make a separate file with a query and the code you posted. Run the code  and see if you still have same issue. Make sure to look in `Application.cfm` or `Application.cfc` files if you have those in your context.
Also you can try inserting `abort` into your code to see if the problem is still there:

```
<cfscript>
  theJSON = SerializeJSON(queryObj);
  writeOutput(theJSON);
  abort;
</cfscript>
```

Comment: It's been a while since I had this issue and luckily I had someone with more cold fusion experience help me track it down. I should have left a comment when I did find it because I've forgotten exactly what it was. However what I do remember is the mvc framework's response that we were using was being wrapped by another process which wrote the xml comment. I think we did use the abort command listed in this answer to help track things down. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

113760 may be either a magic number or the number of bytes being generated. Searching on `<!-- #` or `<cfoutput><!--` or `<!-- <cfouput` might help locate the code that is generating the html comment